# How to using Fat Free framework with Oracle Database

Tags: php, oracle11g, fat-free-framework

how to connect to oracle (11g express edition) database with **Fat Free Framework**?
Currently I am using this config (config.ini):

```
db_dns=oci:host=localhost;port=1521;dbname=
db_name=xe
db_user=username
db_pass=password
```

But it is not working. The error says:

```
Internal Server Error.
could not find driver
```

But I already install the driver (oci8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you build your connection string from that config? try this:

```
$db=new \DB\SQL('oci:dbname=//localhost:1521/xe','username','password');
```

it's from http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.connection.php

Comment: I like the fact that you are always there to help on f3 matters

Comment: I'm totally F3 addicted ^^